# Angular8 cdk: drag and drop not working on grid

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop, angular8

I tried using CDK drag and drop in a single row it worked fine and similarly, it worked fine for single column but
when am using `flex-wrap: wrap` to show tiles in rows and columns, it doesn't work properly.

Here is a demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etbue5

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, what feature you are asking about distributing between columns and rows is not available til you. There is an open issue at github that you can check [Github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13372). So, we need to wait for the feature to be available. For the time being there is an workaround, you can check at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyz1eb)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding and the examples provided in documentation, you can either have row or column orientation but not both

with the property `@Input('cdkDropListOrientation')
orientation: 'horizontal' | 'vertical'`

When you use `flex-wrap`, you create multiple lines (row + column).