# Angular CDK Drag and drop functionality not working when media items are in a flexbox layout

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality for a list of media items in my Angular application. The drag and drop feature works fine when the media items are displayed in a vertical list format, but I'm encountering issues when I try to display them in a horizontal order using flexbox.

I have also tried using `cdkDropListGroup`.Using `cdkDropListGroup` drag and drop happens but sometime for the first and last media item drop not working and the layout is also breaking.

```
<!-- Sliced media list start -->
<ng-template
    *ngTemplateOutlet="
        mediaInputListTemplate;
        context: { media: medias, viewAllMedia: true }
    "
>
</ng-template>
<!-- Sliced media list end -->

<!-- View all media dialog start -->
<p-dialog
    [modal]="true"
    [blockScroll]="true"
    [draggable]="false"
    [resizable]="false"
    [appendTo]="'body'"
    [showHeader]="false"
    [dismissableMask]="false"
    [(visible)]="isAllMediaDialogOpen"
    [maskStyleClass]="'custom-dialog-mask'"
    [styleClass]="'custom-dialog custom-dialog-extra-large'"
>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header"></ng-template>
    <div class="custom-dialog-content">
        <div class="custom-dialog-close">
            <a (click)="onCloseViewAllMediaDialog($event)">
                <span class="material-symbols-rounded"> close </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-dialog-header">
            <h4>
                <ng-container [ngSwitch]="mediaModule">
                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'show'">
                        Trade Show
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
                {{ mediaFileType + 's' }}
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-dialog-body">
            <ng-scrollbar
                [visibility]="'hover'"
                [appearance]="'compact'"
                [autoHeightDisabled]="false"
                [viewClass]="'custom-scrollbar'"
                [pointerEventsMethod]="'scrollbar'"
                [trackClass]="'custom-scrollbar-track'"
                [thumbClass]="'custom-scrollbar-thumb'"
            >
                <div class="custom-dialog-body-inner">
                    <ng-template
                        *ngTemplateOutlet="
                            mediaInputListTemplate;
                            context: { media: medias, viewAllMedia: false }
                        "
                    >
                    </ng-template>
                </div>
            </ng-scrollbar>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-dialog-footer">
            <div class="button-group button-group-end">
                <button
                    class="button button-small button-outline"
                    (click)="onCloseViewAllMediaDialog($event)"
                >
                    <p>close</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p-dialog>
<!-- View all media dialog end -->

<!-- Media input list template start -->
<ng-template
    let-media="media"
    #mediaInputListTemplate
    let-viewAllMedia="viewAllMedia"
>
    <div class="media-input-list" [class.all-media-input-list]="!viewAllMedia">
        <ul cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <ng-container *ngIf="media.length > 0">
                <ng-container
                    *ngFor="
                        let _media of viewAllMedia
                            ? (medias | slice : 0 : 5)
                            : medias;
                        trackBy: trackMediaByIndex
                    "
                >
                    <li>
                        <div
                            cdkDrag
                            class="media"
                            tooltipPosition="top"
                            [pTooltip]="_media.name"
                            [tooltipStyleClass]="'custom-tooltip'"
                        >
                            <div
                                class="media-box"
                                (click)="
                                    onPreviewMediaInNewTab(
                                        $event,
                                        mediaType === 'product_media' ||
                                            mediaType === 'tradeshow_media' ||
                                            mediaType === 'product_hero_image'
                                            ? _media.media_details.media_url
                                            : _media.media_details.thumbnail_url
                                    )
                                "
                            >
                                <img
                                    width="100"
                                    height="100"
                                    imageFallback
                                    [src]="_media.media_details.thumbnail_url"
                                    [fallbackImage]="
                                        './assets/images/no-image.svg'
                                    "
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-actions">
                                <ng-container
                                    *ngIf="
                                        mediaType === 'product_media' ||
                                        mediaType === 'tradeshow_media' ||
                                        mediaType === 'product_hero_image'
                                    "
                                >
                                    <a (click)="onEditMedia($event, _media)">
                                        <span class="icon-update"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </ng-container>
                                <a (click)="onDeleteMedia($event, _media._id)">
                                    <span class="material-symbols-rounded">
                                        close
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngIf="media.length > 5 && viewAllMedia">
                    <li>
                        <div class="media-view-all">
                            <a (click)="onViewAllMedia($event)">
                                <span class="material-symbols-rounded">
                                    add
                                </span>
                                <h6>view all</h6>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<!-- Media input list template end -->
```

```
.media-input-list {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.media-input-list ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 -5px;
}
.media-input-list ul li {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.media-input-list .media {
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    background: var(--white);
    border: 1px solid var(--grey-300);
}
.media-input-list .media-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: var(--grey-100);
}
.media-input-list .media-box:after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.media-input-list .media-box img {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.medias, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

Comment: you can use [cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"](http://doc.liddd.cn/documentation/ionic/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) if you has an horizontal list. But if you have a "list" in two dimension it's not easy. One idea is each element was its own cdk-drop-lisk (you can see this old [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710294/cdk-drag-drop-does-not-correctly-change-the-position-of-images/60712759#60712759)). Exist others solutions, like Md Rafee showed in this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895545/angular8-cdk-drag-and-drop-not-working-on-grid)